# I am trying to perform CURD operation with mongodb along with node.js, but not able to update database data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hi all I am New to Mongodb trying CURD operation pls help me here I am stuck here.
Tried 'update()', this one is also not working.

1. I have created different file for creating a dataBase.
2. **createCollection.js**
3. **insertCollection.js**     // insert data into collection
4. **updateCollection.js**    // getting error here
5. **readCollection.js**

all other files are working correctly, only updateCollection.js showing error.

```
   const getEmpData = require('./createCollection');

   async function main(){
       let collection = getEmpData();
       let query = {name : "lily"};
       let newValues = {$set : {"vehicle" : "Car"} };

       await collection.updateOne(query, newValues, function(err, data){
           if(err) throw err
           console.log('data updated');
       })
   }

   main();


PS C:\Users\NAGESH\Desktop\web Dev\MongoDB\0.project> node .\updateCollection.js
C:\Users\NAGESH\Desktop\web Dev\MongoDB\0.project\updateCollection.js:8
    await collection.updateOne(query, newValues, function(err, data){
                     ^
TypeError: **collection.updateOne is not a function**
    at main (C:\Users\NAGESH\Desktop\web Dev\MongoDB\0.project\updateCollection.js:8:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NAGESH\Desktop\web Dev\MongoDB\0.project\updateCollection.js:14:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: Well, the error means, that `updateOne()` is not a function of `getEmpData()`. Do you have such a function within `createCollection`? Since that is what you require in `getEmpData`.

Comment: Sounds like `getEmpData()` is returning nothing

Comment: yes ,I have a getEmpData() in side createCollection.js

Comment: actually before updating the collection.
(1)I ran  createCollection.js   //successful
(2)then,  insertCollection.js  //successful
(3)then, readCollection.js    //successful
(4)then, updateCollectin.js   //error

Comment: I even place the getEmpData() inside the updateCollection.js file, still not working

Comment: Ok problem is solved.
syntax is : -
(await collection).updateOne(.....)
Now working correctly